# Thread.exit() line:not available error in integrating javafx into swing using jfxpanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, javafx, jframe

I am trying to use fxml inside swing application. The problem now I am facing is the jframe shows up but the javafx components coundn't be seen. No error is given but when debugged, it gives "Thread.exist() line: not available" error. I have the complete code here :-

```
package nonResponsiveButtons;

import java.awt.Color;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NonResponsiveButtons extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NonResponsiveButtons();
    }

    public NonResponsiveButtons(){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                new JFXPanel();
                BottomPanel bottomPanel = new BottomPanel();
                add(bottomPanel);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error in swing utilities thread :" + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });

        this.setSize(600, 600);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        add(jPanel());      


        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel jPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(600,500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        return panel;
    }

    private class BottomPanel extends JPanel{
        private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
        private Pane scenePane;
        private Button btn1;
        private Button btn2;
        private Button btn3;

        private BottomPanel(){
            setSize(600, 100);
            setLocation(0, 500);
            setLayout(null);



            Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    getScenePane().getChildren().addAll(getBtn1(),getBtn2(),getBtn3());
                    getjfxPanel().setScene(new Scene(getScenePane()));

                }

            });
        }

        private JFXPanel getjfxPanel(){
            if(jfxPanel == null){
                jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                jfxPanel.setSize(600,200);
            }
            return jfxPanel;
        }

        private Pane getScenePane(){
            if(scenePane == null){
                scenePane = new Pane();
                scenePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#666666");
            }
            return scenePane;
        }

        /*
         * using getters will avoid :-
         * 1. null pointer exceptions
         * 2. standard coding format
         * 3. makex programming felxible
         */
        private Button getBtn1(){
            if(btn1 == null){
                btn1 = new Button();
                btn1.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn1.setLayoutX(80);
            }
            return btn1;
        }
        private Button getBtn2(){
            if(btn2 == null){
                btn2 = new Button();
                btn2.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn2.setLayoutX(80);
            }
            return btn2;
        }
        private Button getBtn3(){
            if(btn3 == null){
                btn3 = new Button();
                btn3.setPrefSize(100, 50);
                btn3.setLayoutX(80);
            }
            return btn3;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the `JFXPanel` because you haven't added `JFXPanel` to the `BottomPanel`. Inside the constructor of `BottomPanel`, just add `add(getjfxPanel());`

Your constructor will look like this :

```
private BottomPanel(){
    setSize(600, 100);
    setLocation(0, 500);
    setLayout(null);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
           getScenePane().getChildren().addAll(getBtn1(),getBtn2(),getBtn3());
           getjfxPanel().setScene(new Scene(getScenePane()));
       }
    });
    add(getjfxPanel());
}
```

**Note:** After adding this you will be able to see just one `Button`. There is no problem with the code, you are adding Buttons to `Pane`, which is why they are on top of each other. Just replace your `Pane` with a `HBox` and you will be able to see all the buttons because `HBox` aligns controls in horizontal order, just what you want( may be ;) )

Comment: Thank you @ItachiUchiha now my code works properly. Now I want to remove all the components from the Hbox (variable name: scenePane) when btn1 is clicked. i used `getScenePane().getChildren().removeAll();`
to remove all the components of the Hbox but its not working because btn1 is inside scenePane. But when I remove some other component like btn2
`getScenePane().getChildren().remove(getbtn2);`
Then btn2 is removed. How to remove all the components of the scenePane using action listener from its own child

Comment: @Viper You should add a new question, whenever you have further questions(not related to the current) instead of commenting on old questions.

Comment: If `getScenePane()` is returning the `HBox` reference to which `Button` are added, `getScenePane().getChildren().removeAll();` should work !